# Oracle Delete query optimization

Tags: oracle12c, spring-jdbc

```
DELETE FROM   BATCH_T   WHERE   BatchId   In (  BatchIdList  )    AND   Status   = 'CLOSED'
```

The above query is taking 3 mins to finish. Can anybody help me to reduce the response time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the batch list be small, then consider adding the following index to your table:

```
CREATE INDEX batch_idx ON BATCH_T (BatchId, Status);
```

If you have a very long batch list, then consider adding those values to a new table `BATCH_LIST`.  Then, make sure that the following index exists on this new table:

```
CREATE INDEX other_idx ON BATCH_LIST (BatchId);
```

The first index should help either version.

Comment: Indexes are created on status ,batchId columns already. basically i am calling above query from java program using jdbcTemplate.

Comment: Then check the execution plan to whether mine (your) indices are being used.